# Basic topology question

Tags: topology

I am studying topology from the Nakahara book, and I'm trying to understand the concept of usual topology. It's defined in the book as:

> Let $X$ be the real line $\mathbb{R}$. All open intervals $(a, b)$ and their unions define a topology called the usual topology; $a$ and $b$ may be $-\infty$ and $\infty$ respectively.

Doesn't the word "all" imply every possible subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and thus it is reduced to the discrete topology? Also, is the usual topology unique? Because it's obvious that the trivial topology and the discrete topology are unique (given the set $X$), but I cannot completely understand the usual one.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Can you construct the sets $\{0\}$ or $[0,1]$ from unions of open intervals?

Comment: I'm a physics student, and the Nakahara book is mostly focused in applying the techniques to physics, that's why I ask here and not in Mathematics.

Comment: In order to be a discrete topology, all subset of X must be open. Since any element by itself is a subset, there must be one open set for every element. This is different from  "all open intervals...".

Comment: I saw a sign in the park that said "All dogs must be on a leash".  Doesn't the word "all" imply every possible creature, so that I must be on a leash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't the word "all" imply every possible subset of $\mathbb R$?

No, it does not. The book says "all open intervals", i.e. all
$$ (a, b) = \{ x \in \mathbb R: a < x < b \} $$
and their unions. There is no way to write, for example, a single point $\{ x_0 \} \subset \mathbb R$ as a union of open intervals; therefore, the set is not open.

(Proof: If $\{x_0\} = (a, b)$ then $a < x_0$. But then also $\frac{a+x_0}2 \in (a,b)$, but $\frac{a+x_0}2 \neq x_0$.)

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful. From that definition can we infer that the usual topology is uniquely defined?

Comment: No, there's no unique topology. There are infinitely many different topologies - but other choices than "the usual one" will violate your intuition about continuous functions, limits etc.

Comment: The *standard topology on $\mathbb R$* is (of course) uniquely defined, and the definition is given in what you quoted from the book. This does not mean that this is the only topology on $\mathbb R$, for example the trivial and discrete topologies are different.

Answer (score 1):

The topology being defined on $\mathbb{R}$ is:

$$\tau = \left\{U\subset \mathbb{R} : U=(a,b) \ \text{or} \ \exists  \ (a_\lambda,b_\lambda), \lambda \in \Lambda, U=\bigcup_{\lambda\in \Lambda }(a_\lambda,b_\lambda)\right\}$$

Not every subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$ is of this form. Take a finite one $\{-1,0,1\}$ is it an interval? Clearly not. Is it one union of intervals? Clearly not also.

This topology is the same as saying: one open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is open if there is one open interval centered on each point of it entirely contained in the set. Then the set would be one union of such intervals.

This doesn't happen in the example I gave.

By the way, in a more general context he is using the idea of a *basis for a topology*. We define it like that:

> Let $X$ be a set, a basis for a topology on $X$ is a set $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $X$ such that:
>
> 1. If $x\in X$ there is $U\in \mathcal{B}$ with $x\in U$.
> 2. If $U,V\in \mathcal{B}$ with $x\in U\cap V$ then there is $W\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in W\subset U\cap V$.

Every basis allows you to build a topology from it. You can prove for yourself the following proposition (just verify the topology axioms):

> **Proposition**: If $X$ is a set and $\mathcal{B}$ a basis for a topology on $X$ then define $U\subset X$ to be open if for every $x\in U$ there is $B\in \mathcal{B}$ with $x\in B\subset U$. The set $\tau$ of all such open sets is a topology in $X$.

This is the direct generalization of the open balls of $\mathbb{R}^n$. A basis generalizes the concept of the open balls and the basis generated by a topology is a generalization of the topology endowed to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by the open balls.

The converse is also true: for every topology ou can extract a basis. Obviously the topology itself will serve as a basis.